# JPA issue mapping file issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Getting exception

Internal Exception:
(1. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'entity'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":embeddable
}' is expected.)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidEntityMappingsDocument(ValidationException.java:1054)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.xml.XMLHelper.parseDocument(XMLHelper.java:667)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.readExplicitlySpecifiedMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:410)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.readMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:357)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.PersistenceUnitProcessor.buildPersistentClassSetFromXMLDocuments(PersistenceUnitProcessor.ja
va:217)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.PersistenceUnitProcessor.buildClassSet(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:201)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.callPredeploy(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:140)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initPersistenceUnits(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:239)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.JavaSECMPInitializer.initialize(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:255)
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:155)
        ... 10 more
Caused by:
(1. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'entity'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm":embeddable
}' is expected.)

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Offer">
    <table name="S_OFFERS" />
    <named-query name="offersByStatus">
        <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.status=:status</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getAllOffers">
        <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o ORDER BY o.lastUpdateDate DESC</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getOffersByProductLine">
        <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.productLineCode =
            :productLineCode AND NOT o.status = :excludeStatus</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getOfferByOfferCode">
        <query>SELECT o FROM Offer o WHERE o.code = :code</query>
    </named-query>
    <entity-listeners>
        <entity-listener class="com.grc.sdb.listener.CodeGeneratorListener">
            <pre-persist method-name="prePersist" />
            <pre-update method-name="preUpdate" />
        </entity-listener>
        <entity-listener class="com.grc.sdb.listener.BeanChangeActivityListener">
            <pre-persist method-name="prePersist" />
            <post-persist method-name="postPersist" />
            <pre-remove method-name="preRemove" />
            <pre-update method-name="preUpdate" />
            <post-update method-name="postUpdate" />
        </entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="OFFER_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="seqOffers" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqOffers"
                sequence-name="SEQ_OFFERS" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="code">
            <column name="OFFER_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="status">
            <column name="status" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="OFFER_DESCRIPTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="beginDate">
            <column name="begin_date" />
            <temporal>DATE</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="endDate">
            <column name="end_date" />
            <temporal>DATE</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="creation_date" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="created_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="currencyCode">
            <column name="currency_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productLineCode">
            <column name="product_line_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="clubTypeCode">
            <column name="club_type_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="last_updated_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="firstOrderRushAvailableFlag">
            <column name="FIRST_RUSH_AVAILABLE_FLAG" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="firstOrderRushAmount">
            <column name="FIRST_RUSH_AMOUNT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="firstOrderRushMethod">
            <column name="FIRST_RUSH_METHOD_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="mpgCode">
            <column name="MPG_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="contTable">
            <column name="CONT_TABLE_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="edsKeyCode">
            <column name="EDS_KEY_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="availableForCanada">
            <column name="FIRST_CANADA_AVAILABLE_FLAG" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="legacyType">
            <column name="LEGACY_OFFER_TYPE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="continuityKey">
            <column name="CONTINUITY_KEY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="ffcCode">
            <column name="FFC_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <version name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </version>
        <one-to-many name="orderItems" target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OfferItem"
            mapped-by="offer" fetch="LAZY">
            <join-column name="offer_id" referenced-column-name="offer_id" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
        <embedded name="firstOrderDetail">
            <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                <column name="FIRST_NUM_PAYMENTS" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                <column name="FIRST_SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_ADDL_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                <column name="FIRST_CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="payTable">
                <column name="FIRST_PAYTABLE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                <column name="FIRST_BILLING_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_SHIP_UNIT_PRICE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                <column name="FIRST_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            </attribute-override>
        </embedded>
        <embedded name="contOrderDetail">
            <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                <column name="CONT_NUM_PAYMENTS" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                <column name="CONT_SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                <column name="CONT_FIRST_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                <column name="CONT_FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                <column name="CONT_ADDL_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                <column name="CONT_ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                <column name="CONT_CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                <column name="CONT_SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                <column name="CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="payTable">
                <column name="CONT_PAYTABLE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                <column name="CONT_BILLING_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                <column name="CONT_SHIP_UNIT_PRICE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                <column name="CONT_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            </attribute-override>
        </embedded>
        <transient name="firstOrderItems" />
        <transient name="contOrderItems" />
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OfferItem">
    <table name="S_OFFER_ITEMS" />
    <named-query name="removeOfferItems">
        <query>DELETE FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getOfferItem">
        <query>SELECT oi FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id AND
            oi.code=:item_code</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getOfferItems">
        <query>SELECT oi.orderType, oi.code, oi.startCode FROM OfferItem oi
            WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getOfferItemsByType">
        <query>SELECT oi FROM OfferItem oi WHERE oi.offer.id=:offer_id AND
            oi.orderType=:order_type</query>
    </named-query>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="OFFER_ITEM_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="seqOfferItemId"
                strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqOfferItemId"
                sequence-name="SEQ_OFFER_ITEM_ID" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="offerId">
            <column name="OFFER_ID" insertable="false" updatable="false" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="code">
            <column name="ITEM_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="orderType">
            <column name="SHIPMENT_NO" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="startCode">
            <column name="START_ITEM_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="webCartTitle">
            <column name="WEB_CART_TITLE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="webCartText">
            <column name="WEB_CART_TEXT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="webCartMaxQty">
            <column name="WEB_CART_MAX_QTY" />
        </basic>

        <many-to-one name="offer">
            <join-column name="OFFER_ID" nullable="false"
                insertable="true" updatable="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <transient name="description" />
        <transient name="sequenceNumber" />
        <transient name="webCartTextOverridden" />
        <transient name="resetWebCartText" />
        <transient name="webCartTextUpdated" />

    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Item">
    <table name="S_ITEMS" />
    <named-query name="getItemByCode">
        <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
            i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.code=:code</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="getItemByCodeAnyStatus">
        <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.orgCode=:org_code AND
            UPPER(i.code)=:code</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="searchItemsForProductLineByCode">
        <query>SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
            i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.productLineCode=:product_line_code AND
            UPPER(i.code) LIKE :code_filter ORDER BY i.code</query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="searchItemsForContinuity">
        <!-- not checking for status because we want any the Item related to the 
            Continuity even if Inactive -->
        <query>
            SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.orgCode=:org_code
            AND i.code IN
            (SELECT coi.contItemCode FROM ContinuityItem coi WHERE
            coi.continuityKey=:continuityKey)
        </query>
    </named-query>
    <named-query name="countItemsForProductLineByCode">
        <query>SELECT COUNT(i) FROM Item i WHERE i.status=:status AND
            i.orgCode=:org_code AND i.productLineCode=:product_line_code AND
            UPPER(i.code) LIKE :code_filter</query>
    </named-query>
    <attributes>
        <id name="code">
            <column name="item_code" />
        </id>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="item_description" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productLineCode">
            <column name="product_line_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="orgCode">
            <column name="org_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="company">
            <column name="company" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="edsProductNumber">
            <column name="eds_product_no" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="status">
            <column name="item_status" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="invOrg">
            <column name="inv_org" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="invSeq">
            <column name="inv_seq" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="opUnit">
            <column name="op_unit" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="sequenceNumber">
            <column name="SEQ_NUM" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="mnShippingStatusCode">
            <column name="MN_SHIP_STATUS_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="mnShippingReadinessFlag">
            <column name="MN_SHIP_READINESS_FLAG" />
            <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
        </basic>
        <basic name="supplySize">
            <column name="SUPPLY_SIZE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productDescription1">
            <column name="PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION_1" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlan">
    <table name="S_OMX_PAYMENT_PLANS" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="seqPlanId" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqPlanId"
                sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_PLAN_ID" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="cID">
            <column name="CID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="planID">
            <column name="PLAN_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="PLAN_DESCRIPTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="paymentPlanType">
            <column name="PAYMENT_PLAN_TYPE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="recurrenceXML">
            <column name="RECURRENCE_XML" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </basic>
        <one-to-many name="paymentPlanDetails"
            target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlanDetail"
            mapped-by="paymentPlan" fetch="EAGER">
            <join-column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" referenced-column-name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.payment.PaymentPlanDetail">
    <table name="S_OMX_PAYMENT_PLAN_DETAILS" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="OMX_PLAN_DETAIL_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="seqPlanDetailId"
                strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqPlanDetailId"
                sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_PLAN_DETAIL_ID" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="planID">
            <column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="paymentID">
            <column name="PAYMENT_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="delayInDays">
            <column name="DELAY_IN_DAYS" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="fraction">
            <column name="FRACTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="includeSH">
            <column name="INCLUDE_SH" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="includeTax">
            <column name="INCLUDE_TAX" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="includeNonPrimaryProduct">
            <column name="INCLUDE_NON_PRIMARY_PRODUCT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="fixedPaymentAmount">
            <column name="FIXED_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </basic>
        <many-to-one name="paymentPlan">
            <join-column name="OMX_PLAN_ID" nullable="false"
                insertable="false" updatable="false" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </many-to-one>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Continuity">
    <table name="S_CONTINUITIES" />
    <named-query name="getAllContinuityOrders">
        <query>SELECT co FROM Continuity co ORDER BY co.lastUpdateDate DESC,
            co.code ASC</query>
    </named-query>
    <attributes>
        <id name="key">
            <column name="continuity_key" />
            <generated-value generator="seqContinuities"
                strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqContinuities"
                sequence-name="SEQ_CONTINUITY_KEY" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="code">
            <column name="continuity_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="mpgCode">
            <column name="mpg_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="creation_date" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="created_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="last_updated_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productLineCode">
            <column name="product_line_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="ffcCode">
            <column name="ffc_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="firstToContShipInterval">
            <column name="FIRST_CONT_SHIP_INTERVAL" />
        </basic>
        <version name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </version>

        <one-to-many name="items"
            target-entity="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem" mapped-by="continuity"
            fetch="LAZY">
            <order-by>sequenceNumber ASC</order-by>
            <join-column name="continuity_key"
                referenced-column-name="continuity_key" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
        <embedded name="detail">
            <attribute-override name="numPayments">
                <column name="NUM_PAYMENTS" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="numSHPayments">
                <column name="SHIP_NUM_PAY" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstPaymentAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="firstSHAmount">
                <column name="FIRST_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlPaymentAmount">
                <column name="ADDL_PAYMENT" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="addlSHAmount">
                <column name="ADDL_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="canadaSHAmount">
                <column name="CANADA_SHIP_HAND" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipMethod">
                <column name="SHIP_HAND_METHOD_CODE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="shipInterval">
                <column name="SHIP_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="payTable">
                <column name="PAYTABLE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="billingInterval">
                <column name="BILLING_INTERVAL" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="totalPaymentAmount">
                <column name="UNIT_PRICE" />
            </attribute-override>
            <attribute-override name="paymentPlanId">
                <column name="CONT_OMX_PLAN_ID" />
            </attribute-override>
        </embedded>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.ContinuityItem">
    <table name="S_ITEM_CONTINUITIES" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="continuityKey">
            <column name="continuity_key" insertable="false" updatable="false" />
        </id>
        <id name="contItemCode">
            <column name="cont_item_code" />
        </id>
        <id name="startItemCode">
            <column name="start_item_code" />
        </id>
        <id name="sequenceNumber">
            <column name="SEQ_NUM" />
        </id>
        <basic name="omxSOCId">
            <column name="OMX_SOC_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="itemContinuityCode">
            <column name="item_continuity_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="creation_date" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="created_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="last_updated_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productLineCode">
            <column name="product_line_code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="ffcCode">
            <column name="ffc_code" />
        </basic>
        <version name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </version>
        <many-to-one name="continuity">
            <join-column name="continuity_key" nullable="false"
                insertable="true" updatable="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <one-to-one name="backendOffer">
            <join-column name="BACKEND_OFFER_ID" nullable="false"
                insertable="true" updatable="true" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>      
        </one-to-one>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.Soc">
    <table name="S_OMX_SOC" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="OMX_SOC_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="sequenceSocId" strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqSocId"
                sequence-name="SEQ_OMX_SOC_ID" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="cid">
            <column name="CID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="config">
            <column name="CONFIGURATION_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="SOC_DESCRIPTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="recurrencePattern">
            <column name="OMX_RECURRENCE_PATTERN_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="itemCode">
            <column name="ITEM_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="discountPercentage">
            <column name="DISCOUNT_PERCENT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="discountAmount">
            <column name="DISCOUNT_AMOUNT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="noBackorderFlag">
            <column name="NO_BACKORDER_FLAG" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="active">
            <column name="ACTIVE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<embeddable class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.OrderDetail">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="numPayments" />
        <basic name="numSHPayments" />
        <basic name="firstPaymentAmount" />
        <basic name="firstSHAmount" />
        <basic name="addlPaymentAmount" />
        <basic name="addlSHAmount" />
        <basic name="canadaSHAmount" />
        <basic name="shipMethod" />
        <basic name="shipInterval" />
        <basic name="payTable" />
        <basic name="billingInterval" />
        <basic name="totalPaymentAmount" />
        <basic name="paymentPlanId" />
    </attributes>
</embeddable>

<entity class="com.grc.sdb.beans.offer.BackendOffer">
    <table name="S_BACKEND_OFFERS" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="backendOfferID">
            <column name="BACKEND_OFFER_ID" />
            <generated-value generator="seqBackendOffers"
                strategy="SEQUENCE" />
            <sequence-generator name="seqBackendOffers"
                sequence-name="seq_backend_offer_id" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>           
        <basic name="backendOfferCode">
            <column name="backend_Offer_Code" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="backendOfferDescription">
            <column name="backend_Offer_Description" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="creationDate">
            <column name="creation_date" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>
        <basic name="createdBy">
            <column name="created_by" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastUpdatedBy">
            <column name="last_updated_by" />
        </basic>
        <version name="lastUpdateDate">
            <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" />
        </version>
        <one-to-one name="continuityItem">
            <join-column name="continuity_key"  nullable="false" insertable="true" updatable="true"/>
            <cascade>
                <cascade-refresh />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-one>           
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: is this hibernate or toplink?

Comment: It looks like you've posted far too much code/details here, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially the section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to not placing embeddable class before embedded ones. Try changing 
the order.